# using query results in the same function that calls them

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, variables

For some reason I am unable to use query results in the same function that calls them. Please see controller below and model and let me know where my issue is.

What breaks down is line 2 of controller, trying to concatenate query result contact_name and description_computer and saving it as variable name. I get the following error "Undefined variable: query" for both query results.

Using codeigniter.

Controller

```
function get_quarter_info($data)
{
    $data['query'] = $this->model->get_client_info($data);
    $data['name'] = $query['contact_name'] . " " . $query['description_computer'] . ".pdf";
    $html = $this->load->view('Quarter_info_view', $data, true);
    $pdf = pdf_create($html, '', false);
    write_file($data['name'], $pdf);
    $this->index();

}
```

Model

```
function get_client_info($data)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('subscriber_report', array('client_number'=> $data['client_number']));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning a value to `$query` in `get_quater_info`. Instead, you're assigning the value to $data['query'];

Try this instead:

```
$query = $data['query'] = $this->model->get_client_info($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use `$query` instead of `$data['query]`. The `data` array is used to pass data to your view.